# Pass arrays to function

Tags: c, arrays

Apologies for this re-post as I do not know how to phrase my question as it is my first time using stack overflow. I hope someone could help me out in this quiz for my studies.

I had research on this program but I do not know if it relates to the quiz question on arraySize.

Question is below:
we pass array ai to function fillArray. What exactly is passed to the function? The answer is a single memory address, not the 10 integers! This is why we can use the function to fill the array ai with 10 numbers. 
Complete the above function fillArray so that it reads arraySize number of integers from the user and fill the array with those numbers. 
Write a driver program to test the function with integer arrays of different sizes. 
Note the formal parameter int array[] in function fillArray can be changed to int *array. Verify this by modifying and testing your code.

My code is below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 10

int fillArray(int array[], int arraySize);
void print_intaray(int array[], int arraySize);
main()
{
    int ai, exam_scores[MAX];

    printf("***List of Array***\n\n");
    ai = fillArray(exam_scores, MAX);
    print_intaray(exam_scores, ai);
}

int fillArray(int array[], int arraySize)
{
    int ai, count = 0;

    printf("Type array, EOF to quit\n");

    while ((count < arraySize) && (scanf("%d", &ai) !=EOF))
    {
        array[count] = ai;
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}

void print_intaray(int array [], int arraySize)
{
    int i;
    printf("\n***Your Arrary***\n\n");
    for (i = 0; i<arraySize; i++)
        printf("%d\n", array[i]);
}
```

I'm new to programming and I hope my question could somehow be resolve.

Thanks for viewing :)

Comment: So, what exactly is your question?

Comment: what? what's the point?

Comment: I understand what you want to do but what is your question?

Comment: Hi there, I'm asked to create a function fillArray so that it reads arraySize number of integers from the user and fill the array with those numbers and write a driver program to test the function with integer arrays of different sizes. This is as close as I have researched, thinking if this program fits the criteria of the question. :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the question is "Why are `int array[]` and `int *array` equivalent in the function argument":

I'm not much of a C expert, but AFAIK arrays (in C) are largely just pointers to which you append a certain offset. Telling C you expect an `int myarray[]`  means pretty much the same as expecting a pointer to an integer (`int *array`). If you increment the pointer, you can access the next element in the array. This is also known as pointer arithmetic.

The C compiler translates array syntax like `foo[3]` in the background to something like `*(*foo+3)`, but you can also do that yourself by just dealing with the pointers.

Comment: Thanks for your response Thom, I got your meaning but im more worried about the question that is asking to fill the arraySize with inputs by the user, does that mean the output is based on what the user had input? Because based on the above code, my output is exactly what I had input. Furthermore, if the question is asking to write a driver program to test the function, am I correct to write the code based on the above? Somehow confused on the question itself. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: I'm not sure what is meant by a driver program, but it does seem you need to take arraySize inputs from the user and store them in the array.

Comment: Downvoter: please leave a comment so I can improve my question!